How to fix layout of accounts in SiriKit
The app I work on has a SiriKit extension that, as far as I can tell, has no customUI.
When I ask Siri to show me the app's account balances, all looks good.
enter image description here
However, when I tap on one of the accounts, then tap on the back button, the account rows are on top of each other.
enter image description here
Since func handle(intent: INSearchForAccountsIntent, completion: @escaping (INSearchForAccountsIntentResponse) -> Void) has an asynchronous body, I suspected that the display might be thrown off by a timing issue.
But, when I replaced the asynchronous call with a synchronous return of dummy data, I experienced the same issue.
Next, just to try to learn something, I commented out the other method that's implemented for the INSearchForAccountsIntentHandling protocol: func resolveAccountNickname(for intent: INSearchForAccountsIntent, with completion: @escaping (INSpeakableStringResolutionResult) -> Void). Unfortunately, this didn't impact the issue.
Since the UI, as far as I know, is completely handled by Apple, I'm at a bit of a loss about how to debug this. My understanding is that we're passing iOS account data and letting their api's handle the display. Hopefully, I'm missing something.
Please let me know if you want/need more information.
